# PDO mysql: How to know if insert was successful

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm using PDO to insert a record (mysql and php)

```
$stmt->bindParam(':field1', $field1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':field2', $field2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Is there a way to know if it inserted successfully, for example if the record was not inserted because it was a duplicate?

Edit: of course I can look at the database, but I mean programmatic feedback.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

[`PDOStatement->execute()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns true on success. There is also [`PDOStatement->errorCode()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php) which you can check for errors.

Comment: How do you look at the execute() value?

Comment: You store it in a variable? It is either true or false.

Comment: Something like this? $stmt -> execute(); if($stmt){//true} if(!$stmt){//false}

Comment: No more like this, $value = $stmt->execute(); if($value){//true}else{//false}

Comment: Or you can just do `if ($stmt->execute()) { //true }`

Comment: Is `PDOStatement->execute()` and `PDOStatement->errorCode()` totally consistent with each other? Is there any circumstances when `PDOStatement->errorCode()` has something but `PDOStatement->execute()` returns true? Or when `PDOStatement->execute()` returns false but `PDOStatement->errorCode()` has nothing?

Comment: This does not ensure that an insert ever happened!  Only that there was not an error.  It will work if rejected as a duplicate, but not if not inserted based on a WHERE or JOIN.

Comment: What about `query()` function? like this `$db->query("INSERT ..")`, well will it return *true* on success too?

Comment: @MartinAJ although way too late: If you're interested in the affected rows, you should use `$db->exec("Insert...")`, see http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

Comment: But INSERT IGNORE would also return true even if no new record was inserted

Comment: How this is the accepted answer, "Your common sense" 's Answer is correct,  Insert usually throws a fatal error, How can you handle the fatal error with if()  Statement?

Answer (score 31):

Given that most recommended error mode for PDO is `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, **no direct `execute()` result verification will ever work**. As the code execution won't even reach the condition offered in other answers.

So, there are three possible scenarios to handle the query execution result in PDO:

1. To tell the success, no verification is needed. Just keep with your program flow.
2. To handle the unexpected error, keep with the same - no immediate handling code is needed. An exception will be thrown in case of a database error, and it will bubble up to the site-wide error handler that eventually will result in a common 500 error page.
3. To handle the expected error, like a duplicate primary key, and if you have a certain scenario to handle this particular error, then use a `try..catch` operator.

For a regular PHP user it sounds a bit alien - how's that, not to verify the direct result of the operation? - but this is exactly  how exceptions work - you check the error somewhere else. Once for all. Extremely convenient.

So, in a nutshell: in a regular code you don't need any error handling at all. Just keep your code as is:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':field1', $field1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':field2', $field2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
echo "Success!"; // whatever
```

On success it will tell you so, on error it will show you the regular error page that your application is showing for such an occasion.

**Only in case you have a handling scenario** other than just reporting the error, put your insert statement in a `try..catch` operator, check whether it was the error you expected and handle it; or - if the error was any different - **re-throw** the exception, to make it possible to be handled by the site-wide error handler usual way. Below is the example code from my [article on error handling with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors):

```
try {
     $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)")->execute($data);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 1062) {
        // Take some action if there is a key constraint violation, i.e. duplicate name
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
echo "Success!";
```

In the code above we are checking for the particular error to take some action and re-throwing the exception for the any other error (no such table for example) which will be reported to a programmer.

While again - just to tell a user something like "Your insert was successful" **no condition is ever needed.**

Comment: What's the meaning of "Success"? Is that mean a new row inserted, or that means there isn't any error?

Comment: For the INSERT query it's pretty much the same.

Comment: You are right .. Just may you please tell me what about `query()` function?  Can I use try-catch for `query()` instead of `prepared()->execute()` ?

Comment: You should never use query() for inserts in the first place. Insert means there is input and inpout means it should be prepared.

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying. But in this case, all inserted values are made by the application *(they are some random string)*. So I think no need to pass them as prepared statement.

Comment: You better don't make this decision conditional. Just keep it prepared all the way. Besides, if you need to insert more than 1 row you may benefit from multiple execution.

Comment: Agreed .. *multiple execution* is a great advantage of `execute()` function.

Comment: Did you suggest suggest using an Exception to handle an *expected* error...?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt for clarity, I did suggest to *catch* an exception in such a case.

Comment: If it's expected, it's not an exception. Your answer is very badly worded and could lead to all sorts of misunderstandings from beginners -- the very thing you hate on SO.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt feel free to reword it, collaborative efforts are encouraged here. though I cannot think any other term. You catch an error which you expect and don't otherwise. What's so complex in this statement?

Comment: I was always taught that Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances, and for beginners that's a good rule of thumb. Using try ... catch for logic can quickly get out of hand. That said, it seems like a good use in this situation.

Comment: Using MySQL, I had to check if $e->errorInfo[1] == 1062 to verify that the insert failed, because $e->getCode() is always 23000.

Answer (score 9):

Try looking at the return value of [`execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), which is `TRUE` on success, and `FALSE` on failure.

Answer (score 9):

If an update query executes with values that match the current database record then `$stmt->rowCount()` will return `0` for no rows were affected.  If you have an `if( rowCount() == 1 )` to test for success you will think the updated failed when it did not fail but the values were already in the database so nothing change.

```
$stmt->execute();
if( $stmt ) return "success";
```

This did not work for me when I tried to update a record with a unique key field that was violated.  The query returned success but another query returns the old field value.

Comment: If you NEED the record to be inserted, best way is to check like this ............................. .......................  `if($stmt->execute() && ($stmt->rowCount()>0))`

Answer (score 8):

You can test the rowcount

```
    $sqlStatement->execute( ...);
    if ($sqlStatement->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: A reference back to the docs is always helpful @YourCommonSense.
It says " this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications. " but is limited to select firstly, and secondly supported for mysql, which is the subject of this post.

Comment: @crafter Correct. It says that rowCount() can be unrelyable for `SELECT` queries (and even there, the docs speaks about *multiple* queries). It says nothing about `DELETE`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, which seem to be fine to work (the question was about an `INSERT` query). However, I'm new to PDO and if I'm wrong and someone has another references, please write them here. I'm interested to see if there are real disadvantages for the 3 commands above.

Comment: Apart from inconsistency of its own, this answer is also conceptually wrong, for the same reason as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

PDOStatement->execute() can throw an exception

so what you can do is

```
try
{
PDOStatement->execute();
//record inserted
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
//Some error occured. (i.e. violation of constraints)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use id as primary key with auto increment

```
$stmt->execute();
$insertid = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

incremental id is always bigger than zero even on first record so that means it will always return a true value for id coz bigger than zero means true in PHP

```
if ($insertid)
   echo "record inserted successfully";
else
   echo "record insertion failed";
```

Comment: What if I don't need an auto incremented field in my table?

Comment: Who dun? you? with the RESTFul API that is being used so widely auto increment id is like compulsory.

Comment: Why would someone not have a primary and auto increment or any other sequence column? If verification method needed, add any sequential column. If this solution not for You don't add it. It's a fine one to me, I always use some sequential and auto-increment column, so I always have a way to test if my query was successful.