# Confirm record INSERT with PDO and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following will echo `$response` of 1 if there is no error regardless whether a record was inserted.

I read [PDO mysql: How to know if insert was successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661863/pdo-mysql-how-to-know-if-insert-was-successful), however, it just describes if the query was unsuccessful presumably doe to an error.

How can I confirm whether a record was inserted or not?

```
<?php
$sql='INSERT INTO t3(id,data) SELECT id,data FROM t2 WHERE id=?';
$stmt=db::db()->prepare($sql);
$response=$stmt->execute(array(123));
echo($response);
?>
```

Comment: Unless you've set a different error mode, PDO will simply return boolean false on error, or a 1/handle/object on success. Since you're doing an insert, there's no result set, so you'll get a `1` (aka true) back to indicate success.  You can also use [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: @MarcB  `rowCount` would work.  Didn't know if this was my only optino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PDO::rowCount` will return the number of affected rows.

So you could: `echo $stmt->rowCount();`

Answer (score 0):

maybe an awful answer but what about to create a select to find your insert and then simply compare both your insert and your select, or a select with a count with the variables of your input?

Other option may be to check the [last inserted ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)