# How can I know if insert .. select did actually insert any rows?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

Here is my code:

```
$stm = $dbh
->prepare("INSERT INTO resend_pass(user_id, token, date_time)
            SELECT ?, ?, unix_timestamp()
            FROM dual
            WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT count(*) AS num_week,
                                     COALESCE(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))),0)  as num_day,
                                     COALESCE(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  hour))),0) as num_hour,
                                     COALESCE(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 minute))),0) as num_1min
                                  FROM resend_pass
                                 WHERE user_id   = ?  
                                   AND date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
                                HAVING num_week > 11 OR num_day > 5 OR num_hour > 3 OR num_1min > 0 );");

if($stm->execute(array(10, 'token', 10))){
    echo 'inserted';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

My script always prints `inserted`, even when no row inserted. Why? And how can I fix it?

Noted that I've used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661863/pdo-mysql-how-to-know-if-insert-was-successful/37717023?noredirect=1#1661878) to know if it inserted successfully.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`INSERT ... SELECT` is considered successful when it `INSERT`s all the rows returned by `SELECT`; if the `SELECT` returns zero rows then the statement will successfully insert zero rows.

To determine *if* rows have been inserted, one has to test the number of affected rows; with PDO this is done by querying the `PDOStatement::rowCount() method, something like this:

```
try {
    $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT .. SELECT query");
    $stm->execute();
    if ( $stm->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        echo 'inserted';
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No rows inserted');
    }
} catch(Exception $e) { 
    echo $e;
}
```

Comment: Great +1 .. Just can you please rewrite your code and use `try/catch` instead of `if` statement? Like this `if ($stm->rowCount() > 0) throw;`. Also *"No rows found"* and *"failed"* are identical for me.

Comment: Don't you know that PDO can throw exceptions by itself?

Comment: Also I think I can write `$stm->execute(array(10, 'token', 10))` out of that `if` statement, right?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not when *"no row inserted"*. PDO only throws an exception there is an error.

Comment: @YourCommonSense This is an `INSERT ... SELECT`, not a regular `INSERT`. It's possible to successfully insert zero rows.

Comment: Yes I see now. I am thinking how to edit the title and your answer.

Comment: I'd be careful with this. It does not allow you to distinguish between `no row inserted` and `DB error`. The latter may need the admin's attention, or they just may require different handling, so I think it's best to separate them as I did.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Why you don't write `$stm->execute(array(10, 'token', 10))` out of that condition?

Comment: @BeetleJuice That's a god point. As written, my code *would* eat a DB error, wouldn't it?

Comment: @BeetleJuice in fact it does. But it's better to get execute from condition anyway, as it should never return you false, and therefore makes this code misleading.

Comment: @MartinAJ My code is really just meant as a throwaway example. I would expect you do make any alterations or optimizations you see necessary to suit your application.

Comment: Current code has this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean in {path}`

Comment: @MartinAJ Notice `INSERT ... SELECT` will only succeed if all selected rows could be inserted. In case there was any duplicate key, all insertions fail. If you don't want this behavior can also use `INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT` instead, that will insert any record it can and ignore any attempt of inserting duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

`execute` returns `false` only if there was an error.  Your script echoes 'inserted' because there was no error. In short, your query was run successfully. Nothing was inserted because no record met the conditions in your SQL's `WHERE` clause

If you need to know whether a row was actually inserted, call the `rowCount()` function instead:

```
if($stm->execute(...)===false):
    //there was an error
elseif($stm->rowCount()<1): // $stm->affected_rows if you use MySQLi
    //no row was inserted
else:
    //at least one row was inserted
endif
```

[Documentation here.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: PDO throws exceptions, therefore checking the execute() result is quite pointless

Comment: @YourCommonSense I didn't know this; help me with a reference please. The docs on PDOStatement::execute say that "FALSE is returned on failure" and make no mention of exceptions (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: you can simply google for 'PDO exceptions' I believe.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the function `mysqli_affected_rows()`
http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php

If you are using PDO (I think is your case) you may want to try [$stm->rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Prepared statements will return the number of affected rows via that method.

Comment: Yeah I guess `rowCount()` is what I'm looking for. thank you upvote.