# How to tell whether PDO insert was successful?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I’m converting a website that build using MySQLi to PDO.

I search everywhere but I couldn’t find a good example. I just need the proper way of executing a inset query.

Database file

```
$host_name = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "mysql";
$db_name = "mydatabase";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);

    $conn->exec("set names utf8");

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Submit file (witch take data from a user submitted form

```
if($_POST)
{   


$post_title         = $_POST['post'];
$post_cat              = $_POST['post_cat'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posts post_title, post_cat)
    VALUES (:p_title, :p_cat)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':p_title', $post_title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':p_cat', $post_cat);

    $stmt->execute();

    $conn = null;
}
```

This insert the data in to the database without any issue. But how can check whether the rows get inserted or not. And display message "posted" or if there is a error "Failed"

Comment: by getting the last insert id: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php `$conn->lastInsertId();`

Comment: [here is your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37717023/285587). in short, you don't have to check. just print "posted" all the time.

Comment: user try catch as you use in pdo connection

Comment: Jordyn, don't listen to all the comments here but mine. They are wrong.